# Is it possible that adding noise to a signal can increase detection possibility?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, noise, signal-detection

I am simulating a feature detector in noisy environment which consist of AWGN Noise and Impulsive Noise. But I am getting a strange result as Signal with Impulsive+AWGN noise has better detection probability then with Signal with only AWGN. I know its wrong at some point. How Is it possible that signal with more noise like Impulsive noise has better detection possibility. Please share your experience.

Comment: I have found that Sometimes it is possible with AWGN and the process is called Stochastic Resonance. But my signal is neither weak nor I had problem with AWGN because by increasing awgn strength my signal detection probability deteriorate and so is normal, but the abnormal thing is with Impulsive noise because as i increase Impulsive noise strength then it increases signal detection probability. And furthermore Impulsive noise doesn't show stochastic resonance property.

Answer (score 1):

Our ears have a hearing threshold- i.e. a minimum amount of sound power that is required for them to detect.  Thus, a pure tone that is less than the threshold will not be detected.  If white noise is added to the tone such that the total power of the tone and noise exceeds the threshold, then the ear can hear the tone.

Perhaps you have some sort of similar non-linear effect going on.